# adding class name to element from another page

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to add a class name to a div that is loaded form another html page.

```html
<script>
        var item = $('.products').load('products.html #pro-pop');
        item.setAttribute('class', 'product-grid');
    </script>
```

so i loaded a div from another html page suing load() and i want to give it a class name so the css will match the other content on the page i tried doing this but it didn't work.

Comment: use like this `item[0].setAttribute('class', 'product-grid');`

Answer (score 0):

> Try

```
$('.products').load('products.html #pro-pop').find('div').attr('class', 'product-grid');
```